# Mark binaries writable and executable in openBSD

Tags: executable, openbsd, binaries

As of OpenBSD 6.0 mandatory W^X enforcement is implemented.

Binaries that need permission to violate this rule can be marked with the ld command:

> Identify W^X labelled binaries at execve(2) time based upon the WX_OPENBSD_WXNEEDED flag set by ld -zwxneeded.

I tried:

```
    ld -b <binary> -zwxneeded
    ld <binary> -zwxneeded
```

but these give file input/format errors. I've been reading the ld man page but can't figure out the right syntax for file I/O to set the required flag. Any help/advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to add this section is to do it at compile time, by using (for example, if you drive the linking of your application through a compiler that is gcc compatible) the option `-Wl,-z,wxneeded` to your `CFLAGS`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is trivial, mount filesystem where binary is located with wxallowed by editing /etc/fstab accordingly. https://www.openbsd.org/faq/upgrade60.html